# Current time in PartiQL query

Tags: time, timestamp, partiql

How can I get the current time in a PartiQL query? The obvious answer of using the SQL `NOW()` function is not supported:

```sql
PartiQL> SELECT NOW() FROM data;
org.partiql.lang.eval.EvaluationException: No such function: now
    Evaluator Error: at line 1, column 8: No such function: now
```

Answer (score 2):

The builtin function `UTCNOW()` provides ISO 8601 formatted time, and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`gives seconds since UTC expoch. See [BuiltInFunctions.md](https://github.com/partiql/partiql-lang-kotlin/blob/master/docs/user/BuiltInFunctions.md) for the complete list of PartiQL builtins.

```sql
PartiQL> SELECT UTCNOW() FROM data;
===' 
<<
  {
    '_1': `2021-02-11T07:43:58.980Z`
  }
>>
--- 
OK!
PartiQL> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() FROM data;
===' 
<<
  {
    '_1': 1613029453
  }
>>
--- 
OK!
```

Note, *have* to select from something in PartiQL, you cannot do a naked `select now()` like you can in standard SQL.

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns whole seconds by default. Fractional seconds are available by chaining `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` and `UTCNOW()`:

```sql
PartiQL> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTCNOW()) FROM [1];
===' 
<<
  {
    '_1': 1613030587.152
  }
>>
--- 
OK!
```

PS: Thanks for the `FROM [1]` time, Matthew.

Comment: You can also "fake" the from and so a SELECT UTCNOW() FROM [1];


==='
<<
  {
    ‘_1’: `2021-02-10T18:40:25.649Z`
  }
>>
---
OK!